# double integral by Riemann Sums in matlab

Tags: matlab, riemann

```
  clear

  n=45; // widht
  m=23; // length
  // total 990 blocks m*n


  a=-2; b=1; // x-limits
  c=2; d=4;  //  y-limits

  f=@(x,y) 4.0*x.^3.*y+0.7.*x.^2.*y+2.5.*x+0.2.*y; //function

  x=linspace(a,b,n);
  y=linspace(c,d,m);

  h1=(b-a)/n
  h2=(d-c)/m
  dA=h1*h2

  [X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y); //did a meshgrid cause q wouldnt accept different index bounds without meshgriding.
  q=sum((sum(dA*f(X,Y))))
```

Ive been using a formula for double riemanns at this link.
https://activecalculus.org/multi/S-11-1-Double-Integrals-Rectangles.html

these are the answers

1.I=81.3000.

2.I-left=-87.4287 //-84.5523 my result

3.I-Right=-75.1072

I can't see what im doing wrong. I need input from somebody.

Comment: Use natural and comprehensive wording for your question! It's not a title of a book chapter, but a question.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug the integration scheme with a dummy constant function

```
f = @(x,y) 1.0*ones(size(x))
```

The result should be the exact total area `(b-a)*(d-c) = 6`, but your code gives `6.415`.

The problem is that you are integrating outside the domain with those limits. You should stop the domain discretization one step before in each dimension:

```
h1 = (b-a)/n
h2 = (d-c)/m
x = linspace(a, b - h1, n);
y = linspace(c, d - h2, m);
```

This will give you the expected area for the dummy function:

```
q =  6.0000
```

and for the real function, evaluating at the top-left corner, you get:

```
q = -87.482
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong with your code. The difference comes from the resolution of `x` and `y` used in you code, since they are not sufficiently high.

For example, when you have `n = 5000` and `m = 5000`

```
q = sum((sum(dA*f(X,Y)))); % your Riemann sum approach

l = integral2(f,a,b,c,d); % using built-in function for double integral to verify the value of `q`
```

you will see that the results are very close now

```
q = -81.329
l = -81.300
```